# Sort 2D array in C#

Tags: c#, sorting, multidimensional-array, visual-studio-2013

I was trying to compare a 2D array in C# using IComparer but not able to compile the code from my point of view in sort method ab is assumed to be a jagad array instead of a normal array .Does any one know how to solve that

```
int[,] ab = new int[3, 4] 
{ 
    { 1, 2, 3, 4 }, 
    { 5, 6, 7, 8 }, 
    { 2, 3, 4, 5 } 
}; 
Array.Sort<int[]>(ab, new ComparerTwoDArray()); 
foreach (var i in ab) 
{ 
    Console.WriteLine(i); 
} 

class ComparerTwoDArray : IComparer<int[]> 
{ 
    int ix; 

    public int Compare(int[] x, int[] y) 
    { 
        return x[0].CompareTo(y[0]); 
    } 
}
```

Comment: it seems that you are only comparing the first elmenets of the subarrays. Is this on purpose? If not then how do you determine whether one array is **smaller** or **greater** than another? How about this example: `{1,2,1}` and `{1,1,2}` which one is smaller?

Comment: `Array.Sort` supports only one dimentional arrays, so that will not work anyway.

Comment: A jagged array would be `int[3][4]` but your code is about multi-dimensional arrays `int[3,4]`. I suppose your code is your truth and the text is just misspelled.

Answer (score 1):

You are not using the proper method: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.array.sort%28v=vs.110%29.aspx

> Array.Sort Method: Sorts the elements in a one-dimensional array.

You could use `List<List<int>>` and then use its `Sort` LINQ extension, like:

```
list.Sort((x,y) => x[0].CompareTo(y[0]));
```

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately a multi-dimensional array is a quite static beast. You can easily access single elements within it by providing the n-dimensional coordinates (eg. `array[2,8,4]` in a 3d array), but you can't access any whole areas (like rows, columns, rectangles, etc.).

If you really have the need to do such a kind of re-sorting you shouldn't save your data within a multi-dimensional array. Instead put it into a jagged array or a list of lists or even a `IReadOnlyDictionary<int, IReadOnlyDictionary<int, IReadOnlyDictionary<int, int>>>` for a 4 dimensions sparse matrix. In that case you could quite easily write a comparer for each dimension as you like.

In your case you just need a something like `List<IReadOnlyList<int>>` and a `IComparer<IReadOnlyList<T>>` which could possibly be implemented like this:

```
public class ListComparer<T> : IComparer<IReadOnlyList<T>>
{
    public static readonly IComparer<IReadOnlyList<T>> Default = new ListComparer<T>();

    private readonly bool _checkCount;
    private readonly int _numberOfElementsToCompare;
    private readonly IComparer<T> _elementComparer;

    public ListComparer()
        : this(true, 1, Comparer<T>.Default)
    {
    }

    public ListComparer(
        bool checkCount,
        int numberOfElementsToCompare,
        IComparer<T> elementComparer)
    {
        _checkCount = checkCount;
        _numberOfElementsToCompare = numberOfElementsToCompare;
        _elementComparer = elementComparer
            ?? throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(elementComparer));
    }

    public int Compare(IReadOnlyList<T> x, IReadOnlyList<T> y)
    {
        if (ReferenceEquals(x, y))
            return 0;

        if (ReferenceEquals(x, null))
            return -1;

        if (ReferenceEquals(y, null))
            return 1;

        if (_checkCount)
        {
            var diff = x.Count.CompareTo(y.Count);

            if (diff != 0)
                return diff;
        }

        return x.Take(_numberOfElementsToCompare)
            .Zip(y, (i, j) => _elementComparer.Compare(i, j))
            .SkipWhile(value => value == 0)
            .FirstOrDefault();
    }
}
```

And would be used:

```
    var matrix = new List<IReadOnlyList<int>>
    {
        { new List<int> { 1, 2, 3, 4 }  },
        { new List<int> { 5, 6, 7, 8 }  },
        { new List<int> { 2, 3, 4, 5 }  }
    };

    matrix.Sort(ListComparer<int>.Default);

    foreach (var item in matrix)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(String.Join(", ", item));
    }
```